# Creating rows for 5 higher and lower entries with closest matching values in same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm very new to SQL and trying to structure a Java database query to pass in a row identifier code, return the values of all columns in that row, and the 5 closest higher and lower rows to a value in one of the original columns. I can find previous questions using a passed in fixed value, but don't know how to approach it when the value exists in the table.

This is my attempt so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT code, value FROM table1 t1 WHERE code = x) AS a

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from table1 t2 WHERE NOT code = x AND count <= t1.count order by count DESC LIMIT 5) AS b

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from table1 t3 WHERE NOT code = x AND count <= t1.count order by count ASC LIMIT 5) AS c
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Example Table:

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Australia | 15 |
| Mexico | 22 |
| Spain | 36 |
| Nigeria | 87 |
| Poland | 55 |
| Eritrea | 17 |
| Vietnam | 26 |
| Ireland | 107 |
| Sweden | 55 |
| Canada | 26 |

Just as an example, but if I entered Australia as my code, I want to return that and the closest 4:

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Australia | 15 |
| Eritrea | 17 |
| Mexico | 22 |
| Vietnam | 26 |
| Canada | 26 |

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: By closest 4 you mean 2 with greater Value and 2 with less Value, or it could be anywhere as long as they are the closest? Also, what about ties? If there was another Value = 26, would it be returned also (this would make 5 closest)?

Comment: Anywhere as long as they are the closest, and for my specific purpose, as the values are non-duplicate floats it is unnecessary, but may be useful for someone else who needs the same help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicates in the column `Value`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ABS(Value - (SELECT Value FROM tablename WHERE Code = 'Australia'))
LIMIT ?;
```

If there are duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Code = 'Australia' DESC,
         ABS(Value - (SELECT Value FROM tablename WHERE Code = 'Australia'))
LIMIT ?;
```

Change `?` to the total number of rows returned (including 'Australia').

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7152c0e2dc3595425feed49dccf95888).

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs, I really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate sum(Value) into this, if there are multiple rows with the same Code in the table? They both give a misuse of aggregate error when Value is replaced by the sum of values.

Comment: @JTFL check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=18d490f605d7fd8211b7346dc2f41590

Comment: The second one worked perfectly. Absolute legend.